# How to make one column dependent on another in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I follow the Head First SQL for to learn SQL. In the 7th chapter, there is this "T.x ->; T.y" notation for making one column to be dependent on another.  But, I think this is the syntax for MySQL because it didn't work on Postgres. I am little confused. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Never seen that syntax (but I am not a mysql guy). What do you mean by "making one column to be dependent on another"? a foreign key?

Comment: @mxwl Post a link or an example. There's no such syntax in SQL Are you confusing relations with SQL perhaps? One column can be dependent on another but there's no schema clause that enforces this. This is typically enforced using triggers

Comment: Hello, I don't talk about fk because columns are in the same table. I'll try to write the example in the book. super_heroes(name,initial) is our table and it says initial should be dependent on the name column. If we change the name initial should be change as well. Say name = 'Super Guy' and   initial = 'SG' if we change the name to 'Stick Man' initial become 'SM'. Book says if you want to create this relation between these columns you should write "super_heroes.name ->; super_heroes.initial". I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "dependent", are you referring to creating a foreign key - primary key relationship?  If so, you can do this in your table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE MyParentTable(
  c1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  c2 VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE MyChildTable(
  c3 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  c4 VARCHAR(10), 
  FOREIGN KEY (c4) REFERENCES MyParentTable(c1)
);
```

This will make the `c4` column in the child table "dependent" on the `c` column in the parent table.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. But, I don't think the foreign key is the right thing for me because the columns are in the same table. I mean when some value in some column changed the other column -which is dependent on the first one- must be changed as well. For example, we have table_1 it contains two columns which are name and initial. name = 'Super Guy' and initial = 'SG'. If the name changed initial must be changed as well. So, I think there is pk-fk kind of relationship. Book says table.name ->; table.initial statement creates this relationship but I couldn't find the right way for pg

Comment: OK...then you have a couple options:

1) Modify whatever query you have that updates the `name` field in your table to also update the `initial` field at the same time, or 

2) Create a `TRIGGER` that automatically does the update for you.  This way, any query that updates the `name` field will automatically update the `initial` field.  #2 is more work to set up, but less maintenance long-term.